# Vaadin table row change best practice

Tags: vaadin

What is the best way to replace a table row in Vaadin (6 and 7)? I use BeanItemContainer. The bean is an entity and has changed (not the ID).

I think this cause unnecessary method invocation and/or object creation:

```
table.removeItem( item );
table.addItem( item );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, the best pratice is:

```
BeanItemContainer<DataModel> tableDataSource =  new BeanItemContainer<>(DataModel.class);
table.setContainerDataSource(tableDataSource);
```

When you want to replace a row, just replace the **data of this row** in tableDataSource:

```
tableDataSource.removeItem(item);
tableDataSource.addItem(item);
```

The difference between your code and mine is:

- In your code, you replace **the row** (it means the row is removed from the table and then a new row will be added to table).
- In my example, I just replace the **data of row**.

Hope it helps